# Azure Github deployement from private repository

Tags: git, azure, github

I have been deploying my code to a public github repo and it was updating just fine to my Azure website. Then, I tried to make my repository private and the deployments started to fail.

I tried to set it all up again and nothing. Also, I tried to find around people with similar problems and the all answers were dated back to 2012 and all saying: "feature to be implemented soon".

Now we are two year ahead and I see no documentation about it. Do you know how to manage that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy from private GitHub repos. On the Windows Azure Management Portal Dashboard for the web site 1) click on "Setup deplopyment from source control 2) choose GitHub 3) provide your GitHub credentials 4) select repo

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NeilMackenzie ! I tried to do that but I couldn't get it to work either. Thanks

Comment: It is definitely possible to link WAWS and a private GitHub repo. I just tried it out and it worked. Here is a link to a post discussing this as part of a discussion on the recently released staging capability: http://rickrainey.com/2014/01/21/continuous-deployment-github-with-azure-web-sites-and-staged-publishing/

Answer (score 4):

You can deploy from private GitHub repos if you use the old manage.windowsazure.com portal instead of the new portal.azure.com one.

I think it is a bug in the new portal.

Comment: Yep, seems that new portal can't add SSH deploy keys correctly, Old can do it

Just to add a little bit - when you want to deploy from Organisation repository - on authorization step you also should request Organisation access and wait for it to be approved. Otherwise you won't see orgs repositories, only your own forks (even if you're an admin in the org)

Comment: Update: The new portal is now also capable of connecting to private GitHub repos.